# Java Hangman - How to assign letter to JButton when clicked?

Tags: java, arrays, netbeans, jbutton

I have made a basic hangman game on Netbeans, and the way it works is a user clicks one of the 26 buttons (one for each letter of the alphabet) and that letter is tested in the word. The main problem I'm having is getting the letter to be tested.

```
    //array holding all buttons        
    JButton[] alphabet = {AButton, BButton, CButton, DButton, EButton, FButton, GButton, HButton, IButton, JButton, KButton, LButton, MButton, NButton, OButton, PButton, QButton, RButton, SButton, TButton, UButton, VButton, WButton, XButton, YButton, ZButton};

    //getting the current letter(need something in place of the 0)
    String currentLetter = (alphabet[0].getLabel());             

    //replace underscores with letters as they are guessed
                for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                    secretWord = secretWord + currentLetter.charAt(0);
                    foundWord = words[randValue].replaceAll("[^" + secretWord + "]", "_ ");
    }
```

I read somewhere that using a button array is what I had to do, so I put it in but it didn't work. Also, I read that an ActionListener was needed for the program to read what letter it is. Previous tries I have used were:

```
currentLetter = AButton.getText();

currentLetter = AButton.getLabel();
```

but sadly to no avail. So keep in mind that I am using Netbeans and I'm new-ish to Java, so no big elaborate hard stuff, keep it simple. Thanks:)

EDIT:

```
        private void AButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        DoButton.doClick();
}                                       

        private void DoButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
            JButton button = (JButton) evt.getSource();
            String currentLetter = button.getText(); 

        //replace underscores with letters as they are guessed
                        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                            secretWord = secretWord + currentLetter.charAt(0);
                            foundWord = words[0].replaceAll("[^" + secretWord + "]", "_ ");
               }
    }
```

Full Code:

```
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Font;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.util.Random;
    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    import javax.swing.UIManager;
    import javax.swing.plaf.FontUIResource;

    public class MainFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

        public MainFrame() {
            initComponents();
        }

        static String secretWord = "";
        StringBuilder mainWord = new StringBuilder();
        String[] words =         {"technology", "computer", "camera", "graphic", "digital", "media", "technician",
            "photography", "troubleshoot", "pixels", "application", "download"};
        Random r = new Random();
        int randValue = r.nextInt(11)+1;
        String guessWord = words[0];//words[randValue];
        int errors = 0;
        public static int wins = 0, losses = 0;
        String foundWord = null;
        String currentLetter;
        private void RestartButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)         {                                              
            //restart game
                DirectionsFrame DFrame = new DirectionsFrame();
                DFrame.setVisible(true);
                setVisible(false);
                MainFrame MFrame = new MainFrame();
                MFrame.dispose();
                secretWord = "";
                foundWord = null;
                DirectionsFrame.WinsLabel.setText(null);
                DirectionsFrame.LossesLabel.setText(null);
        }                                             

        private void GetButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)         {                                          
            for (int i = 0; i < guessWord.length(); i++) {
                mainWord.append("_ ");
            }
            String SetMain = mainWord.toString();
            mainWord.append(secretWord);
            WordLabel.setText(SetMain);
            GetButton.setEnabled(false);
            AButton.setEnabled(true);BButton.setEnabled(true);CButton.setEnabled        (true);DButton.setEnabled(true);EButton.setEnabled(true);
            FButton.setEnabled(true);GButton.setEnabled(true);HButton.setEnabled        (true);IButton.setEnabled(true);JButton.setEnabled(true);
    KButton.setEnabled(true);LButton.setEnabled(true);MButton.setEnabled(true);NButton.setEnabled(true);OButton.setEnabled(true);
    PButton.setEnabled(true);QButton.setEnabled(true);RButton.setEnabled(true);SButton.setEnabled(true);TButton.setEnabled(true);
    UButton.setEnabled(true);VButton.setEnabled(true);WButton.setEnabled(true);XButton.setEnabled(true);YButton.setEnabled(true);
    ZButton.setEnabled(true);
}                                         

private void ExitButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    // Exit the program
    System.exit(0);
}                                          

private void AButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    DoButton.doClick();
}                                       

private void BButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    DoButton.doClick();
}                                       

private void CButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    DoButton.doClick();
}                                       

private void DButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    DoButton.doClick();
}                                       

private void EButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    DoButton.doClick();
}                                       

private void FButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    DoButton.doClick();
}                                       

private void GButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    DoButton.doClick();
}                                       

private void HButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    DoButton.doClick();
}                                       

private void IButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    DoButton.doClick();
}                                       

private void JButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    DoButton.doClick();
}                                       

private void KButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    DoButton.doClick();
}                                       

private void LButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    DoButton.doClick();
}                                       

private void MButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    DoButton.doClick();
}                                       

private void NButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    DoButton.doClick();
}                                       

private void OButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    DoButton.doClick();
}                                       

private void PButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    DoButton.doClick();
}                                       

private void QButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    DoButton.doClick();
}                                       

private void RButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    DoButton.doClick();
}                                       

private void SButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    DoButton.doClick();
}                                       

private void TButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    DoButton.doClick();
}                                       

private void UButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    DoButton.doClick();
}                                       

private void VButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    DoButton.doClick();
}                                       

private void WButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    DoButton.doClick();
}                                       

private void XButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    DoButton.doClick();
}                                       

private void YButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    DoButton.doClick();
}                                       

private void ZButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    DoButton.doClick();
}                                       

private void DoButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    JButton button = (JButton) evt.getSource();
    String currentLetter = button.getText(); 

//replace underscores with letters as they are guessed
            do {
                for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                    secretWord = secretWord + currentLetter.charAt(0);
                    foundWord = words[0].replaceAll("[^" + secretWord + "]", "_ ");
                //if letter isn't in word
                    if (guessWord.indexOf(currentLetter) == -1) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry, that wasn't in the word.");
                        errors++;
                        if (errors == 1) {
                            Hangman0.setVisible(false);
                        }
                        if (errors == 2) {
                            Hangman1.setVisible(false);
                        }
                        if (errors == 3) {
                            Hangman2.setVisible(false);
                        }
                        if (errors == 4) {
                            Hangman3.setVisible(false);
                        }
                        if (errors == 5) {
                            Hangman4.setVisible(false);
                        }
                        if (errors == 6) {
                            Hangman5.setVisible(false);
                        }
                        if (errors == 7) {
                            Hangman6.setVisible(false);
                        }
                        if (errors == 8) {
                            Hangman7.setVisible(false);
                        }
                        if (errors == 9) {
                            Hangman8.setVisible(false);
                        }
                        if (errors == 10) {
                            Hangman9.setVisible(false);
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You lost! The word was: " + guessWord);
                            losses++;
                            DirectionsFrame DFrame = new DirectionsFrame();
                            DFrame.setVisible(true);
                            setVisible(false);
                            MainFrame MFrame = new MainFrame();
                            MFrame.dispose();
                            secretWord = "";
                            foundWord = null;
                            String strLosses = Integer.toString(losses);
                            String strWin = Integer.toString(wins);
                            DirectionsFrame.WinsLabel.setText(strWin);
                            DirectionsFrame.LossesLabel.setText(strLosses);
                        }
            }
        }
                WordLabel.setText(foundWord.toUpperCase());
            } while (foundWord == null);
            if (foundWord.equalsIgnoreCase(guessWord)) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Yay!");
                wins++;
                DirectionsFrame DFrame = new DirectionsFrame();
                DFrame.setVisible(true);
                setVisible(false);
                MainFrame MFrame = new MainFrame();
                MFrame.dispose();
                secretWord = "";
                foundWord = null;
                String strWin = Integer.toString(wins);
                String strLosses = Integer.toString(losses);
                DirectionsFrame.WinsLabel.setText(strWin);
                DirectionsFrame.LossesLabel.setText(strLosses);
            }
}
```

Comment: @PaulSullivan, a project actually

Comment: kk sounded a bit like homework though :) good luck with your project

Comment: @PaulSullivan, i guess you could call it homework, but I'm doing this of my own accord without it being assigned, and thanks:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an action listener:

```
ActionListener al = new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        Object src = evt.getSource();
        if (evt instanceof JButton) {
            currentLetter = ((JButton) src).getText();
            // do something with letter
        } // else something seriously wrong
    }
};
```

Then add this action listener to each of the buttons in `alphabet`:

```
for (JButton button : alphabet) {
    button.addActionListener(al);
}
```

**EDIT** I don't see the implementation of `initComponents()` in your updated code. Regardless, adding an action listener to each button is something that needs to be done only once. here's how I would start implementing `initComponents()`:

```
private static String[] letters = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F",
    "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R",
    "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z" };
private JButton[] letterButtons = new JButton[letters.length];

private void initComponents() {
    ActionListener al = new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            Object src = evt.getSource();
            if (evt instanceof JButton) {
                currentLetter = ((JButton) src).getText();
                // do something with letter
            } // else something seriously wrong
        }
    };
    for (int i = 0; i < letters.length; ++i) {
        letterButtons[i] = new JButton(letters[i]);
        letterButtons[i].addActionListener(al);
    }
    . . .
    // add all the buttons to the user interface
    . . .
}
```

Please simplify your code by using more arrays! I certainly would not have a separate variable for each letter button or 26 separate methods to deal separately with each letter click.

Comment: could you explain the logic behind this code? and also where would i put this in my code?

Comment: @JavaProdigy - You need an action listener for something to happen when a button is clicked. The action listener is passed an event that has as its source the button that was clicked. The action listener I suggest simply checks that the source is indeed a JButton (as a somewhat paranoid check, I guess) and then accesses the button text to set `currentLetter`. You would put this in the code where you define `alphabet` (or wherever you are initializing the UI).

Comment: when i add it to my code i get this: `ActionListener is abstract; cannot be instantiated`

Comment: @JavaProdigy - Did you import `java.awt.event.ActionEvent`? Did you use the code I posted?

Comment: i did import it, but i'm not understanding `for (JButton button : alphabet) {
    button.addActionListener(al);
}` do i put this in every letter block?

Comment: @JavaProdigy - You should do it once, when you define the `alphabet` array. It's hard to say where it should go in your code without seeing how it is structured.

Comment: @JavaProdigy - There's a lot about your code that I don't understand, but I've updated my answer to suggest a way forward.

Comment: i dont understand it all myself >.< haha i'm getting a bit frustrated. so in netbeans the `private void initComponents()` is in gray code (i cant edit it) so how would i add an actionlistener?

Comment: @JavaProdigy - Oh. You created your class as a JFrame form. Don't do that; you need to be well-versed with the tool to use it for this kind of thing. Just create a regular Java class and then you can edit the code as you see fit. (You can keep the form around as a kind of sample code for what you really want to do. NetBeans does generate some useful template code.)

Comment: thats exactly right. i see what you're saying, if i have future problems I'll post another question, but you got me on the right track. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a single `ActionListener` can be used for every button to determine not only what has been clicked but also to get its text. In your listener, you could use:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    JButton button = (JButton) e.getSource();
    String currentLetter = button.getText(); 
    updateWord(currentLetter);
}
```

Once `currentLetter` is known you could pass it to a helper method, say, `updateWord` to reveal the necessary characters, etc.

```
private void updateWord(String currentLetter) {
 // reveal letters
 // increment 'Hangman' guess counter
}
```

Please read [How to Write an Action Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)

Also consider using an [Action](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) for sharing functionality between buttons.

Comment: so say for instance my first JButton is called `AButton`. Would i replace all instances of `button` above with `AButton`? and would i have to do this for each of my 26 buttons?

Comment: No, `AButton` is just one button. You will need to add an `ActionListener` to _all_ of your buttons. In this case a single `ActionListener` will suffice.

Comment: let me see if i'm understanding. I have 26 blocks of code, one for each of my buttons. take the first one for example: `private void AButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { JButton button = (JButton) e.getSource();
    String currentLetter = button.getText(); 
    DoButton.doClick();` then repeat 25 more times for each button letter? the DoButton holds the code that replaces guessed letters with its letter and unguessed letters with underscores

Comment: No just one 'block' of code (with the `actionPerformed` method I have shown above) - but you register that one block with all your buttons.

Comment: this is what my code looks like (see edit in original post). the `        private void AButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        DoButton.doClick();
}  ` is copied 25 more times, for each button. the coding all looks the same. is this what u meant?

Comment: An `ActionListener` is an interface so cannot be added _without_ its implementation. Please follow the [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) above.

Answer (score 0):

A good solution would not use something like 'AButton', 'BButton' and so on.

As you mentioned you can do it all with an Button-Array (length 26)!

initialize it in a loop, create 26 button instances, and register an ActionListener (always the same, not 26).

You can get the corresponding letter out of the Array-Index!

How? Take the ASCII-Table. Say you want to use Big Letters only, the A has the value 65.

So each buttons corresponds to the letter

> 65 + indexOf(button)
>
> button[0] -> 65+0 = 'A'  button[1] -> 65+1 = 'B'

You get the idea.

The single ActionListener can use the same method to get the corresponding letter:
Something like:

> char theLetter = (char) 65 + buttonArray.indexOf(e.getSource())

And you're done.

I think programming is not about getting it done somehow. You always should look for the perfect solution. If that solution is to hard for you, you should learn how to do it.

Regards!

Comment: could you explain how to do this in java code? and would `char the letter = (char) 65 + buttonArray.indexOf(e.getSource())` be put in my DoButton code? (see edit in original post)

Comment: But anyway: You shoudl use perhaps an ArrayList<Button> buttons=new .... You add the Buttons in a loop: for(int i=0; i<26; i++){ JButton button=new JButton(65+i+""); button.addActionListener(this); buttons.add(button) }

Comment: i've been trying to do this myself but im confused and need help, hence why i posted he question. by add buttons, do u mean add it to the frame?

Comment: no to the arraylist called 'buttons' but of course you will need to add them to the jframe too.